# How to fix NameError: name 'password' is not defined

Tags: localhost, virtualenv

this is my very first code. It works well if I just enter everything correctly. However, if I enter the wrong values at certain points then I get the error "NameError: name 'password' is not defined". Along, with a possible solution if you could review my code and provide me some feedback on how I could make it better than that would be awesome.

I don't know why the password is not defined.
Solutions I have tried: 1. Assigning variable names. 2. Read the book from which I am learning but according to the book my code is fine. 3. Read similar posts but their code is much more advanced so I cannot understand the code nor the solution. 4. Various indentations.`5. The characters in the "" match well.

It just doesn't seem to store the value in the password, how do I store the value in the password?

My Code:

```
def PWCategory():
    print("[pw category]")
    for i in range(0, len(category)):
        print(i+1, ".", category[i])
    print()

def NumPWMaking():
  num_random = string.digits
  password = ""
  for i in range(lang):
    password += random.choice(num_random)
  print(password)


def AlphaPWMaking():
  string_random = string.ascii_letters
  password = ""
  for i in range(lang):
    password += random.choice(string_random)
  print(password)

def NumAlPWMaking():
  string_random = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
  password = ""
  for i in range(lang):
    password += random.choice(string_random)
  print(password)

def NumAlUniPWMaking():
  string_random = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation
  password = ""
  for i in range(lang):
    password += random.choice(string_random)
  print(password)

print("pw making")
lang = int(input("pw digit(4~8): "))

if(lang < 4):
  print("Input value is less than 4.")

elif(lang > 8):
  print("Input value is greater than 8.")

else:
  if __name__ == '__main__':

    category = ("only number", "only alphabet", "number+alphabet", 
"number+alphabet+Special Characters")
    PWCategory()
    select = int(input("Select the number. (exit : 0) : "))
    if(select==0):
      print("exit")

    elif(select==1):
      NumPWMaking()

    elif(select==2):
      AlphaPWMaking()

    elif(select==3):
      NumAlPWMaking()

    elif(select==4):
      NumAlUniPWMaking()

print("pw matching")
searchpw = re.compile("[a-z]+")
matchingpw = searchpw.search(password)
password
if matchingpw == password:
  print("matched pw: ")
  print(matchingpw.group())

else:
  print("I couldn't find it.")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A variable made inside a function is only valid inside the function so edit your NumPWMaking() to:

```
def NumPWMaking():
  num_random = string.digits
  password = ""
  for i in range(lang):
    password += random.choice(num_random)
  print(password)
  return password
```

And convert:

```
elif(select==1):
      NumPWMaking()
```

To:

```
elif(select==1):
      password=NumPWMaking()
```

Similarly do that for other functions.